# Foundation Abide Custom Validator for Credit Card

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

So im trying to validate the Credit Card Number against the card type. Basically if you select mastercard the card number should start only from a 5, visa from a 4 etc.

I have added a jsfiddle below with the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lespr8dc/6/

The form html

```
    <form action="/echo/html/" method="POST" data-abide>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns checkbox-group" data-abide-validator-limit="1,3">
            <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns medium-centered">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                        <label for="card_type">Card Type</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                        <select class="card_type" required="required" data-abide-validator="cType" id="card_type" name="card_type">
                            <option value="">Please select</option>
                            <option value="master" selected="selected">Mastercard</option>
                            <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                            <option value="amex">American Express</option>
                        </select>
<small class="error text-left">Card type is required.</small>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns medium-centered">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                        <label for="card_number">Card Number</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                        <input class="card_number" required="required" data-abide-validator="cNumber" name="card_number" type="text" value="1234" id="card_number">
<small class="error text-left overrides__no-margin">Valid Card number is required.</small>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery Related

```
                        $(document).foundation({
            named_queries: {
                retina_large_up: 'only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)',
                retina_medium_up: 'only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)'
            },
            abide: {
                validators: {
                    cNumber: function (el, required, parent) {
                        //on keyup, start the countdown

                        $(el).on('blur', function () {
                            var validationNumber, error, minlength, maxlength;

                            if (required) {
                                var cardType = $('#card_type').val();
                                var cardNumberDigit = el.value.substring(0, 1);

                                switch (cardType) {
                                    case 'master':
                                        validationNumber = 5;
                                        minlength = 16;
                                        maxlength = 16;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Master Card.';
                                        break;
                                    case 'visa':
                                        validationNumber = 4;
                                        minlength = 13;
                                        maxlength = 16;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Visa Card.';
                                        break;
                                    case 'amex':
                                        validationNumber = 3;
                                        minlength = 15;
                                        maxlength = 15;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Amex Card.';
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        validationNumber = 0;
                                        minlength = 13;
                                        maxlength = 16;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Card Number.';
                                }

                                if (cardNumberDigit == validationNumber && ((el.value).length >= minlength && (el.value).length <= maxlength)) {
                                    error = '';
                                    console.log('done');
                                    //$(parent).find('.custom-error').css('display', 'none');
                                    //console.log(' validationNumber ' + validationNumber + ' error ' + error + ' cardNumberDigit ' + cardNumberDigit);
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    console.log('error');
                                    //$(parent).find('.custom-error').text(error).css('display', 'block');
                                    console.log(' validationNumber ' + validationNumber + ' error ' + error + ' cardNumberDigit ' + cardNumberDigit);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    cType: function (el, required, parent) {
                        //on keyup, start the countdown

                        $(el).on('change', function () {
                            var validationNumber, error, minlength, maxlength;

                            if (required) {
                                var cardType = el.value;
                                var cardNumberDigit = $('#card_number').val().substring(0, 1);

                                switch (cardType) {
                                    case 'master':
                                        validationNumber = 5;
                                        minlength = 16;
                                        maxlength = 16;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Master Card.';
                                        break;
                                    case 'visa':
                                        validationNumber = 4;
                                        minlength = 13;
                                        maxlength = 16;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Visa Card.';
                                        break;
                                    case 'amex':
                                        validationNumber = 3;
                                        minlength = 15;
                                        maxlength = 15;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Amex Card.';
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        validationNumber = 0;
                                        minlength = 13;
                                        maxlength = 16;
                                        error = 'Please enter a valid Card Number.';
                                }

                                if (cardNumberDigit == validationNumber && ($('#card_number').val().length >= minlength && $('#card_number').val().length <= maxlength)) {
                                    error = '';
                                    console.log('done');
                                    //$(parent).find('.custom-error').css('display', 'none');
                                    //console.log(' validationNumber ' + validationNumber + ' error ' + error + ' cardNumberDigit ' + cardNumberDigit);
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    console.log('error');
                                    //$(parent).find('.custom-error').text(error).css('display', 'block');
                                    console.log($('#card_number').val().length);
                                    console.log(' validationNumber ' + validationNumber + ' error ' + error + ' cardNumberDigit ' + cardNumberDigit);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

It has an error and does not actually validate correctly however I am uncertain what might be going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.